# Pause then allow or not a post with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I work with Telerik and when I submit changes from my grid I want to check some data with an AJAX call and then, if the data is OK continue the submit.

I don't really know how the data is submitted but I get it works like a classic form. Is-it possible to "pause" and "restart" the post ?

```
function onSubmit(e) {
    // Pause Submit
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: '/MyController/MyAction/',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (check) {
            if(check)
            {
                // Allow Submit
            }
            else
            {
                alert('error');
                // Stop Submit
            }   
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this way:

```
function onSubmit(e) {
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: '/MyController/MyAction/',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (check) {
            if(check)
            {
                // Allow Submit
            }
            else
            {
                alert('error');
                // stop at error
                e.preventDefault();
            }   
        }
    });
} // end onSubmit
```